# How to securely post data from 3rd party API https page to own server

Tags: php, api, jsonp, checkout

I am using an API where I can put my script on the 3rd party checkout page (https). I need to fetch the details that user is entering on checkout page.

I placed a javascript file and using jsonp ajax request on click of 'Order' button, I am sending the user form information in serialize form to my own server (http).

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.place_order.btn').click(function(){
        var formData = $('form').serializeArray();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'http://myserver-script/test.php',
            crossDomain: true,
            data: formData,
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            success: function(responseData, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                alert('POST Success');
            },
            error: function (responseData, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert('POST failed.');
            }
        });
    })
});
```

What are the steps that I need to follow to make information transfer secure?

Thanks

Comment: Use server side language to transfer your information. PHP is preferred.  I dont think Javascript is a smart way to transfer any kind of confidential information.

Comment: Actually It is just an html page and I can't add any kind of server side scripting on that page. We only can add JS.

Comment: - First of all, I have to changes my server url to https. As It was giving error 'Script was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure script'